# Eliminar valores duplicados en un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una api para encuestas, las respuestas son opcionales y libres. Guardo en un array las respuestas libres, y en otro las opcionales y despues las uno.

Pero el problema es que si el usuario cambia de respuesta se va a seguir guardando en el array duplicando la pregunta.

Lo que necesito es que al guardar la respuesta en el array compare si ya existe ese id de pregunta y borre el anterior y añada el nuevo.

He intendado algo asi pero me borra la respuesta nueva, no la anterior:
Ejemplo, idPregunta es 28 en ambos pero debe eliminar el primero que encuentre, osea el object 1, aunque idRelacion sea diferente:

```html
1: Object
idRelacion: 1212
idPregunta: 28

2: Object
idRelacion: 1111
idPregunta: 28
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-controlled-checkbox-list-forked-w3sgt?file=/src/index.js:0-6231)

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  var respuestas = [];

  const preguntas = [
    {
      idEncuesta: 7,
      encuesta: "Encuesta2 ",
      idPregunta: 26,
      pregunta: "¿Que tan probable es que le recomiende su jefe/a a un colega?",
      listaRes: [
        {
          idRelacion: 11,
          idPregunta: 27,
          idRespuesta: 1,
          respuesta: "Muy probable"
        },
        {
          idRelacion: 22,
          idPregunta: 27,
          idRespuesta: 2,
          respuesta: "Nada probable"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      idEncuesta: 7,
      encuesta: "Encuesta2",
      idPregunta: 27,
      pregunta:
        "¿Qué tan fácil es obtener ayuda de su jefe/a cuando la necesita?",
      listaRes: [
        {
          idRelacion: 158,
          idPregunta: 130,
          idRespuesta: 76,
          respuesta: "Texto libre"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      idEncuesta: 7,
      encuesta: "Encuesta2",
      idPregunta: 28,
      pregunta: "¿Qué tan disponible para los empleados esta su jefe?",
      listaRes: [
        {
          idRelacion: 88,
          idPregunta: 28,
          idRespuesta: 8,
          respuesta: "Nada disponible"
        },
        {
          idRelacion: 99,
          idPregunta: 28,
          idRespuesta: 9,
          respuesta: "Poco disponible"
        },
        {
          idRelacion: 1010,
          idPregunta: 28,
          idRespuesta: 10,
          respuesta: "Moderadamente disponible"
        },
        {
          idRelacion: 1111,
          idPregunta: 28,
          idRespuesta: 11,
          respuesta: "Muy disponible"
        },
        {
          idRelacion: 1212,
          idPregunta: 28,
          idRespuesta: 12,
          respuesta: "Extremadamente disponible"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  var [arrayPreguntas, setarrayPreguntas] = useState([]);
  const [respuestaIdRelacion, setRespuestaIdRelacion] = useState([]);

  var [arrayIdRelacion, setArrayIdRelacion] = useState([]);

  const [respuestaLibre, setRespuestaLibre] = useState([]);

  var [arrayRespuestaLibre, setArrayRespuestaLibre] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setRespuestaIdRelacion((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      idRelacion: parseInt(value),
      idPregunta: parseInt(name)
    }));
  };

  const onblurRespuesta = function () {
    arrayRespuestaLibre.push(respuestaLibre);
  };

  const onblurIdRelacion = function (e) {
    arrayPreguntas.push(respuestaIdRelacion);
    console.log(arrayPreguntas);

    arrayPreguntas = arrayPreguntas.filter(
      (thing, index, self) =>
        index === self.findIndex((t) => t && t.idPregunta === thing.idPregunta)
    );

    console.log(arrayPreguntas);
  };

  const guardar = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayPreguntas.length; i++) {
      arrayIdRelacion.push(arrayPreguntas[i].idRelacion);
      console.log(arrayIdRelacion);
    }

    if (arrayIdRelacion.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < arrayIdRelacion.length; ++j) {
      respuestas.push({
        idRelacion: arrayIdRelacion[j],
        respuestaLibre: arrayRespuestaLibre[j]
      });
    }

    console.log(respuestas);
    //guardarRespuestas();
    respuestas = [];
  };

  return (
    <section style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={guardar}>
          <ol>
            {preguntas.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.id}>
                {item.pregunta}
                <ul className="list-group">
                  {item.listaRes.map((subitem) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      <li
                        name="opciones"
                        className="list-group"
                        key={subitem.idRelacion}
                      >
                        <>
                          <input
                            className="form-check-input"
                            type="radio"
                            name={subitem.idPregunta}
                            defaultValue={subitem.idRelacion}
                            /*  onChange={(e) =>
                              setRespuestaIdRelacion(e.target.value)
                            } */
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            onBlur={onblurIdRelacion}
                          ></input>
                          <label
                            className="form-check-label"
                            htmlFor="exampleRadios1"
                          >
                            {subitem.respuesta}
                          </label>
                        </>
                      </li>
                    </React.Fragment>
                  ))}
                  Obs.
                  <br />
                  <textarea
                    className="form-control mb-2"
                    type="text"
                    required
                    name="respuestaLibre"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    onChange={(e) => setRespuestaLibre(e.target.value)}
                    onBlur={onblurRespuesta}
                  ></textarea>
                </ul>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ol>
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary btn-sm active float-right btn-block"
            type="submit"
          >
            Guardar
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: estuve pensando en algo asi, pero al ejecutar da un error, parece que en algún punto el array se limpia y da indefino , talvez te sirve de algo const onblurRespuesta = function () {
    let ultimo_objeto=null;
    if(arrayRespuestaLibre.length>0)
    for(var i=0;arrayRespuestaLibre.length;i++)
    {
      if(arrayRespuestaLibre && arrayRespuestaLibre[i].idRelacion===respuestaLibre.idRelacion)
      {
        ultimo_objeto=arrayRespuestaLibre[i];
      }
    } 
    if(ultimo_objeto)
      respuestaLibre.idRelacion=ultimo_objeto;
      arrayRespuestaLibre.push(respuestaLibre);
  };

Comment: Asi es marca error de un undefined @HeynerMartinez

Comment: haz un filter al array por el id de pregunta si ya existe eliminala con splie y si no agregala... la verdad suena facil no se si es lo que buscas

Comment: @CristianCamilo si es lo que busco pero no tengo idea de como hacer eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No debes hacer un push debes jugar con los estados si quieres modificar un estado debes usar la funcion que lo setea no hacer uso del push directamente en el estado.

```
const onblurIdRelacion = function (e) {
    let newsAnswer = arrayPreguntas.filter(
      (p) => p.idPregunta !== respuestaIdRelacion.idPregunta
    );
    newsAnswer.push(respuestaIdRelacion);
    setarrayPreguntas(newsAnswer);
    console.log(arrayPreguntas);
  };
```

Te modifique la función **onBLurIdrelacion** el resto está igual

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  var respuestas = [];

  const preguntas = [
    {
      idEncuesta: 7,
      encuesta: "Encuesta2 ",
      idPregunta: 26,
      pregunta: "¿Que tan probable es que le recomiende su jefe/a a un colega?",
      listaRes: [
        {
          idRelacion: 11,
          idPregunta: 27,
          idRespuesta: 1,
          respuesta: "Muy probable"
        },
        {
          idRelacion: 22,
          idPregunta: 27,
          idRespuesta: 2,
          respuesta: "Nada probable"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      idEncuesta: 7,
      encuesta: "Encuesta2",
      idPregunta: 27,
      pregunta:
        "¿Qué tan fácil es obtener ayuda de su jefe/a cuando la necesita?",
      listaRes: [
        {
          idRelacion: 158,
          idPregunta: 130,
          idRespuesta: 76,
          respuesta: "Texto libre"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      idEncuesta: 7,
      encuesta: "Encuesta2",
      idPregunta: 28,
      pregunta: "¿Qué tan disponible para los empleados esta su jefe?",
      listaRes: [
        {
          idRelacion: 88,
          idPregunta: 28,
          idRespuesta: 8,
          respuesta: "Nada disponible"
        },
        {
          idRelacion: 99,
          idPregunta: 28,
          idRespuesta: 9,
          respuesta: "Poco disponible"
        },
        {
          idRelacion: 1010,
          idPregunta: 28,
          idRespuesta: 10,
          respuesta: "Moderadamente disponible"
        },
        {
          idRelacion: 1111,
          idPregunta: 28,
          idRespuesta: 11,
          respuesta: "Muy disponible"
        },
        {
          idRelacion: 1212,
          idPregunta: 28,
          idRespuesta: 12,
          respuesta: "Extremadamente disponible"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  var [arrayPreguntas, setarrayPreguntas] = useState([]);
  const [respuestaIdRelacion, setRespuestaIdRelacion] = useState([]);

  var [arrayIdRelacion, setArrayIdRelacion] = useState([]);

  const [respuestaLibre, setRespuestaLibre] = useState([]);

  var [arrayRespuestaLibre, setArrayRespuestaLibre] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setRespuestaIdRelacion((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      idRelacion: parseInt(value),
      idPregunta: parseInt(name)
    }));
  };

  const onblurRespuesta = function () {
    arrayRespuestaLibre.push(respuestaLibre);
  };

  const onblurIdRelacion = function (e) {
    let newsAnswer = arrayPreguntas.filter(
      (p) => p.idPregunta !== respuestaIdRelacion.idPregunta
    );
    newsAnswer.push(respuestaIdRelacion);
    setarrayPreguntas(newsAnswer);
    console.log(arrayPreguntas);
  };

  const guardar = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayPreguntas.length; i++) {
      arrayIdRelacion.push(arrayPreguntas[i].idRelacion);
    }

    if (arrayIdRelacion.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < arrayIdRelacion.length; ++j) {
      respuestas.push({
        idRelacion: arrayIdRelacion[j],
        respuestaLibre: arrayRespuestaLibre[j]
      });
    }

    console.log(respuestas);
    //guardarRespuestas();
    respuestas = [];
  };

  return (
    <section style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={guardar}>
          <ol>
            {preguntas.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.id}>
                {item.pregunta}
                <ul className="list-group">
                  {item.listaRes.map((subitem) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      <li
                        name="opciones"
                        className="list-group"
                        key={subitem.idRelacion}
                      >
                        <>
                          <input
                            className="form-check-input"
                            type="radio"
                            name={subitem.idPregunta}
                            defaultValue={subitem.idRelacion}
                            /*  onChange={(e) =>
                              setRespuestaIdRelacion(e.target.value)
                            } */
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            onBlur={onblurIdRelacion}
                          ></input>
                          <label
                            className="form-check-label"
                            htmlFor="exampleRadios1"
                          >
                            {subitem.respuesta}
                          </label>
                        </>
                      </li>
                    </React.Fragment>
                  ))}
                  Obs.
                  <br />
                  <textarea
                    className="form-control mb-2"
                    type="text"
                    required
                    name="respuestaLibre"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    onChange={(e) => setRespuestaLibre(e.target.value)}
                    onBlur={onblurRespuesta}
                  ></textarea>
                </ul>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ol>
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary btn-sm active float-right btn-block"
            type="submit"
          >
            Guardar
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```